# Namespace using declaration (C++ Primer - Stanley Lipmann)

Tags: c++

Anyone can help me to understand this statement found in chapter 3 (Library Types) by Stanley Lipmann?

> "Using an unqualified version of a namespace name without a using declaration is an error, although some compilers may fail to detect this error"

I'm having such hard time understanding the semantics of his sentence (english).

Is he trying to say something like the below scenario?

```
int main() {  
  xx::yy  
}
```

where xx is a namespace not defined using the "using" statement and yy is a member?

Comment: There's a great site for asking for the semantics of sentences: http://english.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: As I said before : If you're a newbie, then you don't need to understand EACH and EVERY WORD of the book you read. You just keep reading, and go ahead with whatever you understand at the moment. Once you understand the basic of the language, then you can start reading it again to understand what you didn't understand before!

Comment: @Nawaz i try but i'm the type of person who wants to knows exactly what i'm reading as i go along. I understand what you are saying. Thx

Comment: @yapkm01: In that case, I would suggest you get easier book. C++ Primer is not a primer as such!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

`cout` is a name of the `std` namespace.  The *unqualified* name is `cout`.  The *qualified* name is `std::cout`.  It is an error to use the unqualified name(`cout`) without a `using` declaration beforehand.  You can use either one of the two following declarations:

```
// This brings in the entire std namespace
using namespace std;
```

OR

```
// This only brings in cout.  You would still need to qualify other names,
// such as cin, endl, etc...
using std::cout;
```

Comment: the last sentence (using std::cout;) why is this an error? Are you referring to using the "using std::cout;" declaration is an error? If that is so i understand this last part. Thx

Comment: @yapkm01: Check my answer again.  I tried to make my phrasing a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What he's saying is that the following code should not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() {
  cout << "This is an error!" << endl;
}
```

The `cout` and `endl` names are not defined right now.  They're declared as `std::cout` and `std::endl`, and in order to use them, you can do one of a few things:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() {
  std::cout << "This, I think, is the best way to do it." << std::endl;
}
```

Using the fully qualified name prevents collisions later on: you'll never have something else called `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() {
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  cout << "This is pretty good." << endl;
}
```

Having the `using` statements specify the exact names you're using, and having the `using` statements in the function, can save some typing and makes collisions pretty unlikely.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo() {
  cout << "This works, but isn't good." << endl;
}
```

Importing the entire `std` namespace makes it pretty likely that you'll end up having a function named the same as an `std` function..  You might discover that as soon as you write it, or you might write your function and then later include the header file with the `std` version of the function, at which point your application will mysteriously break.

Comment: In your examples, using `using` actually makes you type **more** characters than when prefixing each object. :-)  I am often amazed at how hard some people (not you in particular) work to attempt to save some work later, and end up with a net loss.

Comment: @Bo Persson: presumably the names would be used several times throughout the function.  The example is necessarily brief...

Comment: @BoPersson: There's more to life than counting characters.

Answer (score 0):

A namespace name is the name of a namespace.

```
namespace A {

}

namespace B = A;
```

The statement says that using a namespace name without a using declaration is an error. But that's not true: The above code is fine, still using the namespace-name `A` as an unqualified name.

Probably it should say the following, to convey its meaning

> "Using an unqualified version of a namespace *member* name without a using declaration
>        *outside the scope of the namespace* is an error, although some compilers may fail to
>        detect this error"

Mentioning the scope is important. The following, for example, is fine too, even though it uses the unqualified version of a namespace member name

```
namespace A {
  int x;
  int &y = x; // x is an unqualified name
}
```

Books should be careful to try and not use slippery language. And even outside the scope of the namespace, the above sentence is not entirely correct because you can also extend the scope of `x` by a using *directive*. Using declarations aren't the only way to name a namespace member outside the namespace using an unqualified name.

Comment: i have not reach that section about defining a namespace yet since I'm still a newbie on C++. However what I was confused about was the term namespace name. I would think of namespace name as the name of the namespace - example std while for example a cout - i would think of that as a name space member. You are so right. A good author would be careful in the choosing of the language cos' every words will have a specific semantic in their meaning. I just find it hard to understand stanley's message.

Comment: @yapkm01, yes, `A` and `B` are namespace-names of that empty namespace. In the C++ Standard, this is specified at section [namespace.def]. And `using A::x;` is a using-declaration. But `using namespace A;` is *not* a using-declaration. It's called a using-directive. Hope I could help.